# Porting to 64-bit with MSVC inline asm that reads [ebp+4]

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86-64, inline-assembly, porting

I'm working in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, and I'm trying to support 64-bit build for my project. And from what I can tell 64-bit architecture is not support __asm keyword.

So here is how it worked when project only supported 32-bit build.

```cpp
void* 
Class1::Class2::operator new(size_t size) 
{ 
void *pCaller;
__asm mov edx, [ebp+4] 
__asm mov pCaller, edx 
char *pMem = (char *) malloc (sizeof(Class2) + size);
doSomething(pMem, pCaller);
void *ptr = (void *) (pMem + sizeof(Class2)); 
return(ptr);
}
```

I can use preprocessor directives to make above function depend on building type.

```cpp
void* 
Class1::Class2::operator new(size_t size) 
{
#ifndef _WIN64  
void *pCaller;
__asm mov edx, [ebp+4] 
__asm mov pCaller, edx 
char *pMem = (char *) malloc (sizeof(Class2) + size);
doSomething(pMem, pCaller);
void *ptr = (void *) (pMem + sizeof(Class2)); 
return(ptr);
#elseif
// Accptable code for 64-bit project.
}
```

I must somehow get rid of those lines

```cpp
__asm mov edx, [ebp+4] 
__asm mov pCaller, edx
```

I have never encounter assembly code before, but from what I can tell

```cpp
__asm mov edx, [ebp+4]
```

is moving data between registers, [ebp+4] is some local variable defined inside function calling `Class1::Class2::operator new(size_t size)` stored on stack. The second line is simply moving data between register and memory.

How can I replace assembly code with C/C++? Is this even possible?

Comment: @rcgldr is right that [ebp+4] is the return address. Whatever doSomething is doing with that address is undoubtedly implementation-specific, so it would have to be rewritten for 64-bit code anyway. So the first step is to see what doSomething is doing with its second parameter and figure out how to write that in an implementation-independent way.

Comment: So how can I return [ebp+4], without using assembly?

Comment: @XYZ123 - i deleted my prior comment. If frame pointers are not omitted, then the code usually starts off with [esp] = return address, then | push ebp | mov ebp, esp | ends up with [ebp+4] == return address. For 64 bit build, the assembly code will need to be in a separate file, and look "backwards' on the stack to find the return address for class2::new(). The assembly code will need to compensate for the pre-allocated area on the stack (usually 32 bytes).

Comment: @XYZ123 - So what does dosomething do with the pCaller parameter?

Comment: You don't want to return [ebp+4], because that doesn't make any sense in 64-bit code. You need to understand what doSomething is doing and figure out the right way to do it in 64-bit mode. Which may or may not require any assembly code, and may even be architecture-independent.

Comment: If it's just the return address you are after, I believe MSVC2010 has [an intrinsic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13185641/2189500) for that.  Note that the sizes of addresses are bigger in x64, which might affect doSomething.

Comment: From what I can remember class2 Is somekind of memory tracker, calling doSomething adds track. I have no longer access to code. Must wait until tomorrow. Will update asap.

Comment: Ha!  Memory tracker was my first guess.  If this is just some kind of leak detection, well, there are a lot of memory tracking tools in the world today.  If this were my code, I'd be tempted to just remove this.  Reduce memory usage, improve performance, simplify code maintenance.  Given the testing required to move to x64 anyway, this might be an ideal time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that EBP is set up as a legacy frame-pointer (which MSVC inline asm forces, I think),
**`[ebp+4]` holds the return address.**  This code is just setting `void *pCaller = return_address`.

This code is just saving the address of the call-site that's allocating the memory.  (Or at least passing it to `doSomething`, along with the address of the memory block).

This may be stopping this `operator new` from inlining into callers, so removing that would be nice.

---

**If you don't need this** (e.g. it's just debugging infrastructure), simply remove that part and just do the `malloc` to implement `operator new`.  Commenters suggest that modern debugging tools can do this for you, making manual instrumentation obsolete.

**Or remove the overloads of `new` and `delete` entirely** to let them use the default C++ `new` / `delete`.

Or apparently MSVC has a [`_ReturnAddress()` intrinsic in `intrin.h`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/returnaddress?view=vs-2019) for the return address, so you can use that for both 32 and 64-bit code instead of inline asm if you really want to keep doing this.

---

**Note that on MSVC, `new` and `delete` aren't compatible with `malloc`/`free`.**  They're separate allocators with separate free-lists and/or bookkeeping formats.

So if other code still wants to use `free()` on these pointers, you do need to keep the overloaded `new`/`delete` for this class even if it doesn't call `doSomething`.  And you need to keep using `malloc` instead of using some other way of calling the default `new`.

But if the only thing that was calling `free` is the corresponding delete operator, you only have one place in your source to change / remove.